# Run code at a specific time regardless of app state

Tags: ios

I want to run some code everyday at 9 AM and 5 PM on iOS.

This should not be depend on application state; whatever state it has, the code must run at a given time, even in background and suspended states.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Google "ios local notifications"

Comment: we cannot create custom repeat intervals.

You have to use on NSCalendarUnit's in-built Unit Time Intervals.

Comment: You cannot execute code at any guaranteed time, particularly not if your app is terminated.  You can use a push notification from your server, but again if your app is terminated then this can only display a notification, it can't execute any code.  You can use PushKIt if you are a VoIP app and this will re-launch your app if it is terminated

Comment: The bottom line is that it's impossible.  There are some mechanisms that might sorta, kinda, sometimes seem to work, but iOS makes no guarantees for any of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to run the app in background and one of them which i'd believe you want is for network access, apple gives you some time to finish the request and update the UI, even if the app is closed. The user should grant access for you to do that, but is also questionable if apple will accept it if you don't do a network request and use it for something else.

Another solution would be silent push notifications, in theory the app should be awaken to execute it without asking the user anything, but you need a server and a network.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to take a look at "local notifications" in iOS. Most documentation you'll find online will talk about UILocalNotification (like for example this nice tutorial here https://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/), but if you're developing an iOS 10 app you need to look at the new UNNotificationRequest class instead because UILocalNotification is deprecated in iOS 10. Have a look at the docs from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest

I hope this sends you in the right direction :)

Comment: This will display a notification, but it won't "call a method"

Comment: True. This will only run app specific code if the user taps the notification. Seems real push notifications is the only way to do this then?